# In a Delta Live Table in Azure Databricks, how can I import a module defined in an adjacent directory?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-asset-bundle

There is a module in a folder one level up

- root

  - mylibs

    - mylib.py
  - pipelines

    - mypipeline.py

mypipeline defines a delta live table. How can I import the mylib module?

The problem is that I cannot get the directory of mypipeline.py since all commands are returning the current working directory.

Comment: Are you using Repos, or it's just a "normal workspace"?

Comment: The code is deployed with DAB to the service principals workspace.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference when the code is running from a Repo vs. code is running from a notebook in a workspace:

- when you use Repo, then the Python's `sys.path` is automatically populated with two entries: current directory and root of the Repo
- when you use a notebook in a workspace, only the current directory is added to `sys.path`

So in you case you will need to have some code in your DLT notebook to add a directory with your package into the `sys.path`. There are two approaches to that:

- detect the current directory automatically and manipulate it to point to `mylibs`. Something like this:

```py
import sys
import os

pipelines_dir_name = "pipelines"
mypipelines_path = [p for p in sys.path
   if p.startswith("/Workspace/") and p.endswith(pipelines_dir_name)]
if len(mypipelines_path) == 0:
  raise Exception("Can't find pipeline directory in sys.path")
if len(mypipelines_path) > 1:
  raise Exception("There are multiple matches")
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(mypipelines_path[0], "..", "mylibs"))
```

- explicitly pass the path to `mylibs` via DLT settings and just do:

```py
sys.path.append(spark.conf.get("mylibs-path-setting"))
```

Comment: Using an absolute from a notebook source like `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../..'))`did not work for me, I have to use a full path like `sys.path.append('/Workspace/Users/<user>/path/to/bundle/root')` in the notebook with dlt code. Only then my imports of custom modules located in other folders then the notebook work.

Comment: Please note that I didn't use a relative path, but constructed it from the existing sys.path